# headless python script requires x-server to Run

Tags: python, python-2.7, image-processing, raster, qgis

I have made a headless script in Python to preprocess Sentinel images and output NDVI [link](https://github.com/ciskoh/GrassPython/blob/Lowermemoryconsumption/SentinelPPN.py).
The script runs on a remote server (linux container) to which I access via SSH connection. The script runs without errors when I launch it from the terminal using:

```
python /home/foo/SentinelPPN.py
```

However, it fails when launched automatically through chronejob. the output being: "cannot connect to X server". I get no other message and no indication of at what line of the script the error occurs

I cannot pinpoint which operation requires the X server, since I do not use the GUI at all and no visual output is created during the script.
In order to launch the script as headless, I use the following settings:

```
import sys
import os
import qgis
from qgis.core import *
#from PyQt4.QtGui import *

app = QgsApplication([],True, None)
app.setPrefixPath("/usr", True)
app.initQgis()
sys.path.append('/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins')
from processing.core.Processing import Processing
Processing.initialize()
```

the rest of the script is mainly processing modules launched using:

```
processing.runalg("...")
```

Could you help me understand why an X server is needed and how can I avoid that?

Comment: On which line is the error?

Comment: I thing [this is a solution](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/263852/using-initqgis-on-headless-installation-of-qgis-3)

Comment: Also the term you should use instated of 'standalone' is 'headless'.

Comment: the error statement doesn't indicate which line causes the crash, not even when I launch it manually

Comment: Tried @MegaIng solution but didn't work for me. The script still needs a connection to an x server. Anymore suggestions?

Comment: Is [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/230940/error-qgis-standalone-script-in-crontab) an answer?

Comment: You could also try [this](https://x.cygwin.com/docs/ug/using-remote-apps.html). But I don't know if that is a permanent solution.

Comment: So thank you @MegaIng. Indeed the problem was with CRON, not with the PyQgis script. Go ahead and make it an answer if you wish...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the cronjob 'blocking' the `DISPLAY` variable, preventing `qgis`/`PyQt4` from correctly initializing. The solution is to tell cronjob to `export` the `DISPLAY` variable:

```
* * * * * export DISPLAY=:0 && python /home/foo/SentinelPPN.py
```

This set the `DISPLAY` to the correct display (That is the `:0`).

<sub>(This was taken from [gis.se](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/230945), because we can't mark duplicate of a none SO question)</sub>